# Redirect to Page after Post Submit

Tags: php, ajax, redirect

I have a form that submits post data to PHP function called search, the search function queries a table I added to the WordPress database. After the submit I would like to redirect to a results page that I added in the dashboard. So far I can only redirect using Ajax, but I would like to redirect from the PHP file.

Ajax

```
$('#finderForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  //e.preventDefault();

  var form = $('#finderForm').serialize();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=search",
    data: form,
    success: function (data) {
      console.log('Submission was successful.');
      console.log(data);
      console.log(window.location.href);
      //window.location.href = '?page_id=7=' + data;
    },
    error: function (data) {
      console.log('An error occurred.');
      console.log(data);
    },
  });
});
```

My Search Function in PHP File, I want to redirect from here:

```
   add_action("wp_ajax_search", "search");

   function search() {
      $name = $_POST['name'];

      $mydb = new wpdb('root','','i3264185_wp1','localhost');
      $query = "SELECT event_name FROM event WHERE event_name LIKE '$name%'";
      $result = $mydb->get_results($query);

      $result = json_encode($result);
      wp_redirect( home_url('/?page_id=7') ); 
      exit;
      echo $result;
      die();
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. If you wish to redirect a user by PHP, you should set the response header. If you output any data, you will not be able to, and you will get a `Header already sent` error.

Look at this line:

```
wp_redirect( home_url('/?page_id=7') ); 
exit;

echo $result;
die();
```

When you use `exit` ( which is the same as `die()` ), you are terminating the script. The next lines will never be executed. So my suggestion is to either use AJAX to redirect, or change your form to something like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo admin_url ( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>">

    <!-- This is to set the action of your query args -->
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="search"/>

    <!-- Rest of your form here -->

</form>
```

Then, remove the line after `exit` and also the AJAX script, if you aren't relying on it for something important.